# Extracting System.Title from JSON with Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to extract the `System.Title` value into a variable from below JSON file. I got stuck with the "Not an array reference" error. Can you help?

```
    my $json_text = do {
        open(my $json_fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $filename2)
            or die("Can't open \$filename2\": $!\n");
       local $/;
       <$json_fh>
    };

    my $json = JSON->new;
    my $data = $json->decode($json_text);

    for ( @{$data->{fields}} ) {
       print "$_->{\"System.Title\"}.\"\n\"";
       #@witems = "$_->{System.Title}";
       push @wtitle,"$_->{\"System.Title\"}";
       chomp @wtitle;
       #print "@wtitle";
    }
```

**JSON file Content:**

```
{
    "id": 2110,
    "fields": {
        "System.CommentCount": 1,
        "System.Title": "preprocessing with arrays",
        "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedBy": {
            "displayName": "firstname, lastname",
            "url": "https://dummyURL.com/4002-8be/_apis/Identities/6d91-9b75",
            "_links": {
                "avatar": {
                    "href": "https://azure.com/CARS/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/aad.OS03ZDkxLTliN"
                }
            },
            "id": "6d91-9b75",
            "descriptor": "aad.OS03ZDkxLTliN"
        },
        "kanbanboard.Column": "To Do",
        "kanbanboard.Column.Done": false
    },
    "_links": {
        "fields": {
            "href": "https://azure.com/CARS/ORG-ID/_apis/wit/fields"
        }
    },
    "url": "https://azure.com/CARS/ORG-ID/_apis/wit/workItems/2110"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fields` is a hash reference, not an array reference.

```
my $json_text = do {
    open(my $json_fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $filename2)
          or die("Can't open \$filename2\": $!\n");
    local $/;
    <$json_fh>
};

my $json = JSON->new;
my $data = $json->decode($json_text);

print "$data->{fields}{'System.Title'}\n";
```

This prints:

```
preprocessing with arrays
```

I used [Data::Dumper](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data::Dumper) to show the structure of `$data`:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($data);
```

Answer (score 4):

As the error says, you're trying to use something as an array reference that isn't an array reference.

You can use `Data::Dumper` to inspect variables:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print $data->{fields}, "\n";
```

This tells you it's a hash reference:

> HASH(0x7fbd6d80ec90)

So you can just access that hash and pass the key name you want, e.g., "System.Title".

I also would advice you to always `use warnings;` and `use strict;`.

The whole code looks like this (putting the example JSON in a data section at the end of the code, which makes it easier for small examples like here):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

$/ = undef;
my $json_text = <DATA>;
my $json = JSON->new;
my $data = $json->decode($json_text);

use Data::Dumper;
print $data->{fields}, "\n";

print ${$data->{fields}}{'System.Title'}, "\n";


__DATA__
{
    "id": 2110,
    "fields": {
        "System.CommentCount": 1,
        "System.Title": "preprocessing with arrays",
        "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ResolvedBy": {
            "displayName": "firstname, lastname",
            "url": "https://dummyURL.com/4002-8be/_apis/Identities/6d91-9b75",
            "_links": {
                "avatar": {
                    "href": "https://azure.com/CARS/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/aad.OS03ZDkxLTliN"
                }
            },
            "id": "6d91-9b75",
            "descriptor": "aad.OS03ZDkxLTliN"
        },
        "kanbanboard.Column": "To Do",
        "kanbanboard.Column.Done": false
    },
    "_links": {
        "fields": {
            "href": "https://azure.com/CARS/ORG-ID/_apis/wit/fields"
        }
    },
    "url": "https://azure.com/CARS/ORG-ID/_apis/wit/workItems/2110"
}
```

Comment: Most people would write your second print statement as `print $data->{fields}->{'System.Title'}, "\n"`